# Is there a way to retrieve data from MongoDB without the _id field?

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver

I am using MongoDB in our project and I'm currently learning how things work.

When inserting records, MongoDB auto generates the ID. When querying data, it always returns _id. This creates a problem when we deserialise the Bson/Json to out objects as our types don't have that field (and we don't really want to put it in).

Does anyone know how to retrieve data without getting _id in the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just explicitly omit it:

```
collection.Find(criteria)
    .SetFields(Fields.Include("oneField", "anotherField").Exclude("_id"))
```