# mongoexport without _id field

Tags: json, mongodb

I am using mongoexport to export some data into .json formatted file, however the document has a large size overhead introduced by _id:IDVALUE tuples.

I found a similar post [Is there a way to retrieve data from MongoDB without the _id field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594436/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-data-from-mongodb-without-the-id-field) on how to omit the _id field when retrieving data from mongo, but not exporting. It is suggested to use: `.Exclude("_id")`. I tried to reqrite the --query parameter of mongoexport to somehow include the `.Exclude("_id")` parameter, but all of the attempts failed so far.

Please suggest what is the proper way of doing this, or should I revert to using some post-export techniques?

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There appears to be no way to exclude a field (such as `_id`) using mongoexport.

Here's an alternative that has worked for me on moderate sized databases:

```
mongo myserver/mydb --quiet --eval "db.mycoll.find({}, {_id:0}).forEach(printjson);" > out.txt
```

On a large database (many millions of records) it can take a while and running this will affect other operations people try to do on the system:

Answer (score 15):

This works:

```
mongoexport --db db_name --collection collection_name | sed '/"_id":/s/"_id":[^,]*,//' > file_name.json
```

Comment: @Gianfranco P. , if mongo documents contain "_id" keyword on other locations,  will that also replaces?

Comment: @JosephD good question. it doesn't as `sed` is matching the double-quotes. Here's the test I did https://gist.github.com/gianpaj/df6470cb24f82659580200828f6873bc

Comment: Thanks @Gianfranco P. , and that sed is checking for matches in "_id" only . r8?

Comment: @JosephD yep. see https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-sed-to-find-and-replace-string-in-files/

Answer (score 12):

Pipe the output of `mongoexport` into `jq` and remove the `_id` field there.

```
mongoexport --uri=mongodb://localhost/mydb --collection=my_collection \
  | jq 'del(._id)'
```

**Update**: adding [link to jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

Answer (score 9):

I know you specified you wanted to export in JSON but if you could substitute CSV data the native mongo export will work, and will be a lot faster than the above solutions

```
mongoexport --db <dbName> --collection <collectionName> --csv --fields "<fieldOne>,<fieldTwo>,<fieldThree>" > mongoex.csv
```

Answer (score 6):

`mongoexport` doesn't seem to have such option.

With [ramda-cli](https://github.com/raine/ramda-cli) stripping the `_id` would look like:

```
mongoexport --db mydb --collection mycoll -f name,age | ramda 'omit ["_id"]'
```

Comment: Trying this but keep getting the _id. ```mongoexport --db enso --collection places --out placesType.json -f "name,city,latitude,longitude,objectID,type" --jsonArray | R 'omit ["_id"]'``` Getting must specify --save, --no-save, or --vanilla. I tried each one and go same output with _id and this console error ```ARGUMENT 'omit' __ignored__

ARGUMENT '["_id"]' __ignored__```. Any ideas?

Comment: I also get error for "specify --save, --no-save, or --vanilla"

Answer (score 5):

I applied quux00's solution but `forEach(printjson)` prints [MongoDB Extended JSON](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) notation in the output (for instance `"last_update" : NumberLong("1384715001000")`.

It will be better to use the following line instead:

```
db.mycoll.find({}, {_id:0}).forEach(function (doc) {

    print( JSON.stringify(doc) );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mongo <server>/<database> --quiet --eval "db.<collection>.find({}, {_id:0,<field>:1}).forEach(printjson);" > out.txt
```

If you have some query to execute change `""` to `''` and write your condition in `find` with `""` like `find("age":13)`.

Answer (score 1):

With **[jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)** this can be achieved easily:

```
mongoexport -d database -c collection --jsonArray | jq 'del(.[]._id)'
```

Comment: this jq command is needed when using `--jsonArray`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to exclude the sub-document information such as the "_id" is to export it as a csv, then use a tool to convert the csv into json.

Answer (score 0):

**mongoexport** can not omit "_id"

**sed** is a powerful command to do it:

```
mongoexport --db mydb --collection mycoll -f name,age | sed '/"_id":/s/"_id":[^,]*,//'
```

The original answer is from [Exclude _id field using MongoExport command](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/HwM2ccw5dW4)

Answer (score 0):

Just use **--type=csv** option in mongoexport command.

```
mongoexport --db=<db_name> --collection=<collection_name> --type=csv --field=<fields> --out=<Outfilename>.csv
```

For MongoDb version 3.4, you can use **--noHeaderLine** option in mongoexport command to exclude the field header in csv export too.

For Detail: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/

Answer (score 0):

export into a file and just use replace empty value  using  Regular expression, in my case

```
"_id": "f5dc48e1-ed04-4ef9-943b-b1194a088b95"
```

I used `"_id": "(\w|-)*"`,

Answer (score -7):

Have you tried specifying your fields with the `--fields` flag? All fields that are not mentioned are excluded from the [export](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongoexport/).

For maintainability you can also write your fields into a seperate file and use `--fieldFile`.

Comment: Yes, I did so from the very beginning, and was surprised to find the _id field in the exported file. I just double checked that, and the _id field is indeed exported.

Comment: I just iterated and removed items with "_id" key.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption--fields) 
> For JSON output formats, mongoexport includes only the specified field(s) and the _id field, and if the specified field(s) is a field within a sub-document, the mongoexport includes the sub-document with all its fields, not just the specified field within the document.