# How do I remove _Id field using mongoexport?

Tags: mongodb, export

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mongoexport without _id field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976145/mongoexport-without-id-field)

How do I remove the _Id field when using mongoexport?

> $ ./mongo
>   MongoDB shell version: 2.2.2
>   connecting to: test
>   > db.coll.insert( {first: "John", last: "Doe"} )
>   > exit
>   $./mongoexport --db test --collection coll --out out.json --fields 'first,last'

out.json:

> { "_id" : { "$oid" : "50bc20b3cef5182e2a788fc9" }, "first" : "John", "last" : "Doe" }

instead of:

> { "first" : "John", "last" : "Doe" }

Comment: Maybe not what you are looking for, but exporting in csv format exclude the "_id" field.

Comment: mongo <server>/<database> --quiet --eval "db.<collection>.find({}, {_id:0,<field>:1}).forEach(printjson);" > out.txt

If you have some query to execute change `""` to `''` and write your condition in `find` with `""` like `find("age":13)`.