# Removing the index of a collection in mongoDB?

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoid

I want to remove the id of my document in MongoDB.

I will put the document below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54f2324671eb13650e8b4569"),
    "nome" : "Pr.Ademar Lourenço",
    "tweet" : "Jornal Águas Lindas: Prefeito Hildo se reúne com governador Rollemberg e prefeitos do Entorno http://t.co/PtVWIENdO4"
}
```

I want you to be like this:

```
{
    "nome" : "Pr.Ademar Lourenço",
    "tweet" : "Jornal Águas Lindas: Prefeito Hildo se reúne com governador Rollemberg e prefeitos do Entorno http://t.co/PtVWIENdO4"
}
```

The reason and I'll export this document to a .txt and treats it out of MongoDB.

Comment: I would like mu is too short, but I'm newbie in mongoDB. I do not know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mongoexport to export data in either json or csv format. There is a --fields option to this utility that will let you define which specific fields to export

```
--fields nome,tweet
```

Adjusting the examples in the reference documentation: http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/mongoexport/ to your example.

For JSON

```
mongoexport --db sales --collection contacts --fields nome,tweet --out contacts.json
```

For CSV

```
mongoexport --db users --collection contacts --fields nome,tweet --csv --out contacts.csv
```

Hopefully this gives you enough to export your data into the form you want.

Comment: Thanks for answering nomDePlum, I exported the document without _id but it was only in .csv format. But .json format, from what I understand, you can not export without the _id.

Comment: Hi Eduardo I wasn't aware of this limitation of mongoexport when exporting to JSON.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976145/mongoexport-without-id-field has what looks like a reasonable solution. I haven't tried it but hopefully it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a query and remove the _id field in projection parameter, example:

db.tweets.find({}, {_id:0});

this will remove the column _id in response.

Comment: Thanks for answering seduardo, Research works well. But, I was wondering how I could export my document so that is in research.