# Compare a mongo diff on two collections

Tags: mongodb, collections, diff

I have two mongo collections, one which refers to the production env and the other to the testing env.

How can I compare a diff between my two collections?

I tried dumping them to a bson and then converting to a json. But I cant just perform a simple diff on them since the sorting might vary and the json file is way too large to be sorted.

Answer (score 17):

Try the following in the shell, it will iterate each item within a collection and try to match each document based on ID.

Say we have 2 collections `db.col1` and `db.col2`:

```
> db.col1.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 3, "item" : 3 }
{ "_id" : 4, "item" : 4 }

> db.col2.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 3, "item" : 3 }
{ "_id" : 4, "item" : 4 }
```

We can then create a javascript function to compare 2 collections

```
function compareCollection(col1, col2){
    if(col1.count() !== col2.count()){
        return false;
    }

    var same = true;

    var compared = col1.find().forEach(function(doc1){
        var doc2 = col2.findOne({_id: doc1._id});

        same = same && JSON.stringify(doc1)==JSON.stringify(doc2);
    });

    return same;
}
```

Then call is like the following:

```
> compareCollection(db.col1, db.col2)
true
```

If we then have a 3rd collections `db.col3`

```
> db.col3.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : 1 }
```

And compare this one

```
> compareCollection(db.col1, db.col3)
false
```

we'll get the expected result.

If we also have a 4th collection which has matching documents but diffrent data `db.col4`

```
> db.col4.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : 10 }
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 3, "item" : 3 }
{ "_id" : 4, "item" : 4 }
```

This will also return `false`

```
> compareCollection(db.col1, db.col4)
false
```

Comment: What if I've got 5 million records? Wouldnt that result in some performance issues? Isnt there a straighter way?

Comment: If you have 5 million records... the only way to compare them is to check all 5 million, I guess if you had something else in your document that made them unique you could just compare against that and have that as an index, but if you need to check that they match you need to check that they match 

Comment: [Mingo.io](https://mingo.io) has a feature that does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 12):

Starting `Mongo 4.4`, the aggregation framework provides a new [`$unionWith`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/unionWith/#unionwith-aggregation) stage, performing the union of two collections (the combined pipeline results from two collections into a single result set).

Making it way easier to find the diff between two collections:

```
// > db.test.find()
//    { "a" : 9, "b" : 2  }
//    { "a" : 4, "b" : 12 }
//    { "a" : 3, "b" : 5  }
//    { "a" : 0, "b" : 7  }
//    { "a" : 7, "b" : 12 }
// > db.prod.find()
//    { "a" : 3, "b" : 5  }
//    { "a" : 4, "b" : 12 }
//    { "a" : 3, "b" : 5  }
//    { "a" : 0, "b" : 7  }
db.test.aggregate(
  { $unset: "_id" },
  { $project: { from: "test", doc: "$$ROOT" } },
  { $unionWith: {
      coll: "prod",
      pipeline: [
        { $unset: "_id" },
        { $project: { from: "prod", doc: "$$ROOT" } }
      ]
  }},
  { $group: {
      _id: "$doc",
      test: { $sum: { $cond: [ { $eq: ["$from", "test"] }, 1, 0 ] } },
      prod: { $sum: { $cond: [ { $eq: ["$from", "prod"] }, 1, 0 ] } }
  }},
  { $match: { $expr: { $ne: ["$test", "$prod"] } } }
)
// { "_id" : { "a" : 7, "b" : 12 }, "test" : 1, "prod" : 0 }
// { "_id" : { "a" : 9, "b" : 2  }, "test" : 1, "prod" : 0 }
// { "_id" : { "a" : 3, "b" : 5  }, "test" : 1, "prod" : 2 }
```

This:

- `$unset`s the `_id` in order to latter be able to `$group` documents by themselves without considering the `_id` (as it might be different in the other collection).
- `$project`s the field `from` whose value is the collection the document comes from (`test` or `prod`), in order, latter when we merge the two collections, to keep track from where documents originated from.
- Also `$project`s the field `doc` whose value is the document itself (thanks to the [`$$ROOT`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/aggregation-variables/index.html#variable.ROOT) variable). This is the field that will be used to `$group` documents together.
- `$unionWith` the `prod` collection in order to merge documents from both collections into the same aggregation pipeline. The `pipeline` parameter is an optional aggregation pipeline applied on documents from the collection being merged (`prod`) before documents are inserted into the downstream pipeline. And we're applying the same `$unset`/`$project` stages we've applied on `test` documents.
- `$group`s `test` and `prod` documents based on the `doc` field that we've created to represent the actual document. And we accumulate the two fields `test` and `prod` as the `$sum` (count) of grouped documents originating from one or the other collection (via `$cond` if expressions).
- `$match`es resulting grouped elements by only keeping items not having the same number of test and prod documents: the actual diff between the two collections.

Comment: Will it work for array elements?

Answer (score 10):

The [dbHash](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/dbHash/) has done the trick:

```
use db_name
db.runCommand('dbHash')
```

It returns the hash values for each collection. You can then compare them. It's pretty accurate.

Comment: It didn't return same hash for two collections with the same data.

Comment: _id will always lead to hash mismtach

Answer (score 10):

Using the [Kevin Smith response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41223773/2363144), I have a new version, only for compare and return those ID's who the `collectionB` don't have comparing with the `collectionA`. And save the result in a `collectionC` when you have lots records.

```
    db.collectionA.find().forEach(function(doc1){
        var doc2 = db.collectionB.findOne({_id: doc1._id});
        if (!(doc2)) {
                db.collectionC.insert(doc1);
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is the best, most concise answer, thank you Carlos. Note: i had to delete `doc1.__v` and `doc2.__v` before stringifying the two docs when comparing them.

Comment: @chichilatte How did you delete the variable?

Comment: @Mallik just with a line like `delete doc1.__v` inside that forEach callback function

Answer (score 4):

If you need to compare only a subset of fields (e.g. you don't need to compare ids), you can do it the following way. Export the collections to csv, specifying the fields to compare ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32314925/304209)):

```
mongoexport -d <db_name> -c <col_name> --fields "field1,field2" --type=csv | sort > export.csv
```

And then do a simple `diff` on the csv files. Note that column order in the csv file corresponds to the `--field` option.

Pros:

- you can specify subset of fields to compare.
- you can see the actual diff of the records.

Cons:

- to compare the full records, you need to know all possible fields.
- `mongoexport` can be slow for huge databases.

To get all fields in all documents in a collection, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43570730/304209).

Answer (score 1):

`mongoexport` now has a `--sort` option:

For example:

```js
$ mongo
test> db.coll.insertMany([
  { _id: 0, name: 'Alex' },
  { _id: 1, name: 'Bart' },
  { _id: 2, name: 'Maria' },
  { _id: 3, name: 'Aristotle' },
]);
{
  "acknowledged": true,
  "insertedIds": [
    0,
    1,
    2,
    3
  ]
}
```

Export it:

```sh
mongoexport -d test -c coll --sort "{name: 1}"
2018-10-25T15:50:07.210+0300    connected to: localhost
{"_id":0.0,"name":"Alex"}
{"_id":3.0,"name":"Aristotle"}
{"_id":1.0,"name":"Bart"}
{"_id":2.0,"name":"Maria"}
2018-10-25T15:50:07.210+0300    exported 4 records

mongoexport -d test -c coll --sort "{name: -1}"
2018-10-25T15:49:42.010+0300    connected to: localhost
{"_id":2.0,"name":"Maria"}
{"_id":1.0,"name":"Bart"}
{"_id":3.0,"name":"Aristotle"}
{"_id":0.0,"name":"Alex"}
2018-10-25T15:49:42.011+0300    exported 4 records
```

After you exported the collections you can perform a `diff` in the command line or use a graphical user interface (GUI) tool like Beyond Compare.

FYI: if your documents might have the same data but have different `_id` values:
You can exclude the `_id` field when exporting like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49895549/728287

Answer (score 0):

use Studio 3T to compare mongodb.
you can compare collections,db,single records as well.
just you need to download and connect mongo.
here is download link https://studio3t.com/

Comment: Maybe you might add some link to some tutorial on how to do it in that specific tool.

Comment: Especially because this feature is not a part of the free edition (not even of the "cheap" license), but only of the Enterprise edition... If someone does have the tool though, here's the link to the real tutorial: https://studio3t.com/whats-new/diff-mongodb/?utm_source=post&utm_medium=fb&utm_campaign=3tslpage